# How to access current authenticated user from within FormRequest class method

Tags: validation, laravel, input, laravel-5

I have a User model with two functions to check gender of the user. For a particular Form I've created a `FormRequest` object. Now, I need to setup some validation rules which are specific to users gender, i.e. for male users there is a set of rules and for female users there is another set of rules.

Here is my User model:

```
// app\User.php
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract {

    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;

    public function is_male()
    {
        return $this->gender == Gender::male();
    }

    public function is_female()
    {
        return $this->gender == Gender::female();
    }

    public function profile_ok()
    {
        return $this->status == 'OK';
    }
}
```

Now in the `FormRequest` Class, There is a `authorize()` mehtod to check if the user is logged in and have access to the form, which uses `Auth::check()`method and `Auth::user()->profile_ok()` method(), which works withhout throwing up any errors. But in the `rules()` method when I try to access current user via `Auth::user()->is_male()` it throws up an error saying,

```
FatalErrorException in ProfileRequest.php line 34:
Class 'app\Http\Requests\Auth' not found
```

Here is my FormRequest Class:

```
// app\Http\Requests\ProfileRequest.php
class ProfileRequest extends Request {
    public function authorize()
    {
        if ( !Auth::check() )
        {
            return false;
        }
        return Auth::user()->profile_ok();
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        if(Auth::user()->is_male())
        {
            return ['rule1' => 'required',]; //etc
        }
        if(Auth::user()->is_female())
        {
            return ['rule2' => 'required',]; //etc
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I access The current user from within the rules() method?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do it by `$this->user()`